# $scope outsite $on listener return undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have this small piece of code that it is not working:

```
$scope.$on('play', function(e, data) {
   $scope.tick = (data.time*100)/2.5;
});
console.log($scope.tick);
```

If I log `$scope.tick` outside `$on` return `undefined`. I can't understand why, I need to access that var outside the event listener.

This is the code triggering the `$on`

```
angular.module('videoCtrl', ['vjs.video'])
  .controller('videoController', ['$scope', 'Timeline', function ($scope, Timeline) {
        $scope.mediaToggle = {
            sources: [
                {
                    src: 'http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4',
                    type: 'video/mp4'
                }
            ],
        };

        //listen for when the vjs-media object changes
        $scope.$on('vjsVideoReady', function (e, videoData) {
          videoData.player.on('timeupdate', function () {
            var time = {
              time: this.currentTime()
            };
            $scope.$broadcast('play', time);
          })
        });
    }]);
```

and here the one receiving it:

```
angular.module('mediaTimelineCtrl', ['mt.media-timeline'])
    .controller('DemoMediaTimelineController', function ($scope, Timeline) {
    $scope.tick = 100;
    $scope.disable = false;
    $scope.timelines = Timeline.getTimelines();

    $scope.$on('play', function(e, data) {
      $scope.tick = (data.time*100)/2.5;
    });
    console.log($scope.tick);
});
```

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$on` is a method provided by angularjs that allows you to listen for a specific broadcast at which point the provided function will be executed.

You log the variable right after you registered your callback that sets the `tick` variable. At this point your callback simply hasn't been called yet. For this to happen you must use `$scope.$broadcast('play', data)` somewhere in your code(Depending on wher you call `$broadcast` you might have to use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`, because broadcast only sends the events to child scopes.(See angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) for more info)

**Edit**: This has been resolved in chat now. The callback provided in $on was called correctly, but the video library that is being used here called the event outside of an angular `$digest` cycle. Wrapping the assignment of $scope.tick into `$scope.$apply([...])` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but if I log that var inside `$on` has a value.

Comment: Exactly. Because the function you provided is not called right away, but only after is has been triggered by an event. The log statement right under the call to `$on` however is executed **before** an event has been fired(using `$broadcast` or `$emit`). It's important to know that you simply provide the function in the call to `$on`, but that it's not actually called right away

Comment: What I should do to make accessible outside?

Comment: It is accessible outside, but not set until the first event is received and the callback has been executed.  You simply have to assigned an initial value(e.g. `$scope.tick = 0`)

Comment: I wrote more of my code. It's the same of my other question except that now  videoCtrl is parent of mediaTimelineCtrl

Comment: Well I can now see that you actually initialize `$scope.tick` with 100. If it really logs undefined now, that's pretty weird.

Comment: nope, now it logs 100 but doesn't change with the new value.

Comment: Can you confirm that the callback you provided to `$scope.$on` and `videoData.player.on` are actually being called? If `$on` is not being called try broadcasting on the root scope: `$rootScope.$on('playit', time);`. Of course you have to inject the `$rootScope` in the videoCtrl

Comment: I'm pretty newbie on angular as you can see. How I can Check it?

Comment: Just add some `console.log('$on called')`(different messages for multiple console logs of course, so you can distinguish them) in the functions and then check the browser console to see which ones were called.

Comment: Nope, it's not called, what I should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142978/discussion-between-angus-simons-and-riiverside).

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.$on` use to listen to the events that fired by the `$broadcast` or an `$emit`. until one of those event fires, `on` function is not gonna fire and the content of the `on` function will not gonna execute.

But since the console log is outside of the `on` function it will execute whether `scope.on` fires or not. that is why conosole.log shows undefined.

if you put the console inside the `scope.on` function then it will execute only when the event fires

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$scope.tick` is updated only when the event is fired. At the end of first digest cycle the value of `$scope.tick` is still undefined. You have to initialize the value of `$scope.tick` first or use `$watch` `[$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);]`. `watchExp` The expression being watched. It can be a function or a string, it is evaluated at every digest cycle. `listener` A callback, fired when the watch is first set, and then each time that during the digest cycle that a change for `watchExp‘s` value is detected. The initial call on setup is meant to store an initial value for the expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't understand what you mean...I should use `$watch` instead of `$broadcast` and `$on`?

Comment: I guess you want to sync the value of `this.currentTime()` and `$scope.tick`?

Comment: You can share data using a service. http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/2/ or using .value http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/3/ . I'm not sure how `this.currentTime()` populating the value. You can still write a separate service for that one. Or use `$watch` on the source of  `this.currentTime()` function which is responsible for data.